# Installing ffmpeg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ffmpeg

I am not an expect with linux and new to rails but trying i am trying to have my user allowed to upload video and to view them. Now I have found this gem for ruby on rails https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg which seem to use paperclip and the ffmpeg software to upload video on my server. However in the documentation it state you must install ffmpeg and i am not sure how. I use ubuntu 12.04 and not sure how to install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a question for SO. You should ideally ask such questions on superuser. However to install ffmpeg just do

```
 sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu repository normally have old builds for ffmpeg and will not contain some current features.
It's better practice to download ffmpeg from [source](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) and build it.

For ubuntu you can follow this process for build and install:

extract the tar file and go inside ffmpeg folder
execute following commands

```
$ ./configure
$ make -j 10
$ sudo make install
```

If you wish to configure ffmpeg with some option you can provide parameters like

```
./configure --enable-libx264 --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-gpl --enable-version3
```

Answer (score 0):

[FFMPEG installation Guide - Official](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/)
for Linux , Windows , MacOS and other platforms. (Includes guide for developers )