# How to increase time limit of ADB screen record of Android Kitkat

Tags: android

I was using screen record functionality of ADB to record video of my application. It is very convenient and useful. Only issue I found is maximum time limit of 3 minutes (180 seconds).

Is there any way or workaround or way by which we can increase this time limit?

Comment: What is your goal? If all you want to do is to record a video of your application, you can use https://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/

Comment: The SO question you link to has nothing to do with `screenrecord`.

Comment: Oh.. updated question by removing last line

Comment: @NunChai - Does this screencast link you sent record videos on actual device or desktop? Because if this works on desktop then I already have softwares for recording video. I want to record video on actual device so that I can capture smoother animation effects and can capture high quality video like adb screenrecord does

Comment: It will record whatever you do on the device to a path on the Computer, provided by you.

Comment: Great! I will give it a try

Comment: The website for AndroidScreencast says: "Current limitations: Slow refresh rate (about 4-5 fps)"
No one wants to record a screencast with such low framerates, might as well take screenshots.

Comment: @Mathieu Please ignore. I thought you were talking about `screenrecord`. My bad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On windows my trick is creating a `screenrecord.bat` file and running it. For 9 minutes:

```
adb shell screenrecord --bit-rate 8000000 /sdcard/sr1.mp4
adb shell screenrecord --bit-rate 8000000 /sdcard/sr2.mp4
adb shell screenrecord --bit-rate 8000000 /sdcard/sr3.mp4
```

Then you can merge the files with any video editing software.

I know this is a lame solution but `adb screenrecord` is to blame for not allowing longer video lengths...

Comment: Hi ercan, this is workaround for task I want to accomplish but it works

Comment: On mac/unix, you could then automatically stitch these files together with something like this: `mkvmerge -o sr.mp4 sr1.mp4 \+ sr2.mp4 \+ sr3.mp4`. See https://askubuntu.com/a/831883/268299 for more information.

Comment: For MacOS you can also merge the files using QuickTime and choose the option "Edit -> Add Clip to End..." without having to install additional software

Answer (score 14):

I encounter the same problem.

Here is my solution. Briefly speaking, it can be solved by recompiling the android source. Patients are needed.

1, Following the instruction here  https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html  to initialize a build environment.

2, Download the source code from git (Take about 1 hour with 10 M bandwidth).

3, Modify the path_to_working_directory/frameworks/av/cmds/screenrecord/screenrecord.cpp by changing the `kMaxTimeLimitSec` to 7200 (means 2 hours).

4, Compile the android (Take about 2 hours with Core i5-2500k and 8G RAM)

5, Copy the path_to_working_directory/out/target/product/flo/system/bin/screenrecord to  /system/bin in your android phone (Remember to make backup of origin screenrecord in case!)

Comment: Have you tried put your re-compiled executable in your app's private directory, instead of copy it to /system/bin (which requires root permission I suppose)? does it still work?

Comment: I haven't tried this. And the recompiled version of `screenrecord` has been removed for a while. So I now try to put the original `screenrecord` to /sdcard/Download, and it does work normally. You can give it a try.

Comment: This is an amazing solution! I used a [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com) VM to compile one as per your instructions. I checked out the branch for Android 4.4.4_r1 (since that's my target device) and did a `make` then extracted the file from `<pwd>/out/target/product/generic/system/bin`. If you want my version of screenrecord (records for **10 days** max - GO NUTS!), [click here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8ueg6WQMioKdFJfNVVfRE90UGc). If you want help setting up and compiling one yourself, just ping me.

Comment: BTW, you will need to get root access and install it in `/system/bin` (rename the old one to `screenrecold`). It doesn't work if you just copy into the phone (internal/external SD card) and try to run it as `./screenrecord` ... you will get permission errors. Also remember to `chown root:shell` and `chmod a+x` after installing in `/system/bin`.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I solved it.  ***Make sure you backup screenrecorder some place before you go messing with it.***  I know that the max time is 180 seconds, and is stored in a 32-bit integer.  In hex, this would be B4 00 00 00.  So I loaded up screenrecorder into ghex, (my hex editor), and searched for B4 00 00 00.  There were only a few candidates.  On the 6th try, I found the location where the constant was stored.  In my version it was at offset 0001B008.  I changed the B4 to D4, which is 212 decimal, and screenrecorder ran for 3 min 32 sec. So then I changed it to 10 02 00 00, which would be 210 hex, which is 528 dec, and it ran for 8 min 48 sec.  So I changed it to 10 00 01 00, which would be 10010 hex, which is 65552, and it ran... well, it's still running.

I didn't want to mess with recompiling my OS, I just wanted to change this one constant in the screenrecorder program.  So I did.  You have to have root permissions to overwrite the screenrecorder, and I had to remount my system folder because it was mounted as read-only.  I did that with the command:  **mount -o rw,remount /system**

It would have been awesome if the developers had written screenrecorder to default to 180 seconds, but allowed you to set whatever max timeout you wanted.  It's an open source project.  I should probably figure out how to submit a patch.

Cheers

Comment: My version on Armv7 did not have that value as a 32 bit int, but it was in a cmp.  I used Hopper Disassembler (demo) to find that place (Find > Hexa Value > b4), and replaced the cmp with a cmp that would pass the following jump.

Comment: Awesome Michaël, you are a true hacker.  What's also cool about this solution is that once you set the max time limit value to a very large number, you can always set it to a smaller number on the command line with --time-limit=n  where n is whatever number of seconds you need.  You can also stop it with a Ctrl-C, or kill it from within your program with a kill( pid, SIGINT); command, (where pid=screenrecorder process id).

Answer (score 6):

An alternative solution:

```
adb shell "screenrecord --time-limit 5 /sdcard/testRun1.mp4; screenrecord --time-limit 5 /sdcard/testRun2.mp4"
```

Notice the quotes and the semi-colon. The shell command is executed as a shell script on the Android device. The command above would create two mp4 files of 5 seconds each, one after the other.

In our Jenkins test projects we do an exec step with a command like this:

```
adb shell "screenrecord /sdcard/test1.mp4; screenrecord /sdcard/test2.mp4; screenrecord /sdcard/test3.mp4" &
```

The ampersand backgrounds the adb command to allow the rest of the test script to proceed. The command above will record up to 9 minutes.

Answer (score 6):

```
#!/bin/bash
```

## Function to keep stream going after 3mins

```
screenStream() {
while true
do
adb exec-out screenrecord --output-format=h264 --size 1024x768 - 
done
}
```

## Unique file name variable

```
SecondString=$(date +%s)
```

## Display to screen

```
screenStream | ffplay -framerate 30 -framedrop -bufsize 16M -
```

## Save to file

```
screenStream | ffmpeg -i - -s 1024x768 -framerate 30 -bufsize 16M $SecondString.mp4
```

#Ctrl+C to exit.

Answer (score 3):

#### Elegant solution using ffmpeg

Here is an oneliner to record screencast into a local file without time limits:

```bash
adb shell "while true; do screenrecord --output-format=h264 -; done" | ffmpeg -i - screencast.mp4
```

Note: `ffmpeg` utility required to run this command

#### Explanation

This command recursively runs `adb shell screenrecord` command, pipes the output to the ffmpeg utility, and stream the result to a file named "screencast.mp4" using h264 encoding:

Comment: will try this. Tx for sharing

Comment: Amazing solution! You can also replace `shell` with `exec-out` if you need and it still works.

Answer (score 1):

Collecting all previous answers here to a single coherent BASH script.
ffmpeg (ffplay) is required ([how to install ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486448/installing-ffmpeg))

`capture-screen.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# Usage:
# bash ./capture-screen.sh
# bash ./capture-screen.sh -s 192.168.1.10

ADB_FLAGS="$@"

CAPTURE_BITRATE=2000000
CAPTURE_HEIGHT=720
CAPTURE_WIDTH="$((($CAPTURE_HEIGHT / 9 * 16)))" # automatically calculate width

# this call will fail if no single device could be selected
adb ${ADB_FLAGS} shell uptime

screenStream() {
  while true; do
    adb ${ADB_FLAGS} exec-out screenrecord --output-format=h264 --bit-rate ${CAPTURE_BITRATE} --size "${CAPTURE_WIDTH}x${CAPTURE_HEIGHT}" -
  done
}

screenStream | ffplay -hide_banner -framerate 60 -framedrop -f h264 -i -
```

Also available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mrbar42/91bfaeba6fbe85e19144387a5666ab35)